# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module - error with import in webpack

Tags: webpack

I have a global file with my constants defined, and in this file I use import. When trying to import these constants into webpack.config using require, when I run webpack it gives an error because it does not support the import that is in the constants file.

How can I get around this?

```js
// webpack.config.js
const { token } = require('./constantes.js');
```

```
error:
constantes.js:1 (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import angular from 'angular'; ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Answer (score 0):

Node.js provides a CommonJS module format which provides a `require()` function to import other CJS modules using relative path or from `node_modules`.

The ESM is a new standard format for writing JavaScript Modules and is not compatible with CommonJS and thus you cannot use `require()` function to import the ESM modules.

You webpack configuration i.e. `webpack.config.js` is written in CommonJS format while the `constantes.js` file is write in ESM format.

There are couple of way to address this. Either change the webpack configuration to ESM by renaming it as `webpack.confg.mjs` or rewrite `constantes.js` to CommonJS.

Another option is to use dynamic import to load the `constantes.js` function.

Comment: What would this dynamic import look like?

Comment: @loris, It would be `const constants = await import('./constantes.js')`. But it is not the approach I would recommend unless there is really need for it as it introduces async behavior in you code.